# R: Plotting points from a .gdb file over polygons in a shapefile

Tags: r, gis

I'm trying to overlay two different kinds of geospatial data in R (I don't have access to ArcMap, nor can I install any additional software on my workstation).  I am able to map polygons with no problem, but I'm having trouble plotting points on top of those polygons.  The points seem to be plotting relative to a different coordinate system.  If I resize the graphics window containing all of my plotted data together, the points do not stay in a constant location relative to the underlying polygons (although all of the polygon layers stay in constant alignment relative to each other).  My guess is that I'm doing something wrong in importing the points from the .gdb file, but I'm not sure what.  I've tried changing the projection on the .gdb files to match those in my shapefiles, but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Note: One of my layers has many polygons.  To speed loading, I imported the data using readShapeSpatial and then saved the resulting object to an .rdata file.

The code is below:

```
require(RColorBrewer)
require(GISTools)
require(maps)
require(rgdal)
require(maptools)

# latitude and longitude limits
lat_lims  = c( 26.2,  30.8)
long_lims = c(-98.2, -88.0)

load("map2100a1Hi5.rdata")
plot(map2100a1Hi5, lty=0, ylim=lat_lims, xlim=long_lims)

par(new=T)
basemap = readShapeSpatial("cb_2013_us_state_500k.shp")
plot(basemap, xlim = long_lims, ylim = lat_lims)

projection = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83")
layers = ogrListLayers("RefineriesGulfCat1.gdb")
refineries =   readOGR("RefineriesGulfCat1.gdb", layer=layers[4])
refineries = spTransform(refineries, projection)
par(new=T)
plot(refineries, ylim=lat_lims, xlim=long_lims)
```

Comment: Did you try `plot(basemap, xlim = long_lims, ylim = lat_lims); plot(refineries, add = T)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up converting the points to SpatialPoints, which caused them to plot correctly. Not sure why this was necessary, but it works.

```
plot(SpatialPoints(refineries@coords), ylims=lat_lims, xlims=long_lims)
```